# Apply same validation rule for multiple fields

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

How do i apply same validation rule for 50 fields in 2.0

i am not interested in repeating rule for different field

```
public $validate = array(
    'company' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Cannot be Empty',

        ),
    ),
    // rule for other 50 fields....
);
```

Comment: Always a good idea to specify which version of Cake you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
$validate_items = array('company', 'other', 'one_more');

$validate_rule = array(
    'notempty' => array(
        'rule' => array('notempty'),
        'message' => 'Cannot be Empty')
    );

$validate = array();

foreach ($validate_items as $validate_item) {
    $validate[$validate_item] = $validate_rule;
}

echo "<pre>".print_r($validate, true)."</pre>";
```

Don't understand why you want to determinate same validation 50 times. You can declare just one rule and use it for all your fields.

May be I misunderstood your question?

Comment: for 50 different fields i want to apply not empty

Comment: "You can declare just one rule and use it for all your fields." how do i do this

Comment: what fields do you want to validate? $_POST massive?

Comment: First of all you'll have to create an array of the fields you want to check. Next you have to create a loop throuw your $_POST and check wether the field have to be checked. If true, check it like that if ($_POST[$current] == "") $valid = false; further can do check on $valid. If false, do nothing with data.

Comment: What if I have, say 30 fields with their own validation rules to set up, but 15 of them have the same rather complex rule that I don't want to repeat. How do I combine that?

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically build your $validate rules before you perform the save in your controller:

public function add() {

```
if (!empty($this->request->data) {

    $validate = array();

    foreach($fields as $field) {
        $validate[$field] = array(
            'required'=>array(
                'rule'='notEmpty',
                'message'=>'Cannot be empty'
            )
        );
    }

    $this->ModelName->validate = $validate;

    if (!$this->ModelName->save($this->request->data)) {
       // didn't save
    }
    else {
       // did save
    }

}
```

}

Where $fields is an array containing a list of the fields you want to apply the validation to.

Idealy, You'd shift the code that builds the validation array to the model, but the effect is the same

You can apply the same technique to allow you to have multiple validation rules for a model.

Answer (score 0):

New example:

```
$fields_to_check = array('company', 'field_2', 'field_5'); // declare here all the fields you want to check on "not empty"

$errors = 0;

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($key, $fields_to_check)) {
        if ($value == "") $errors++;
    }
}

if ($errors > 0) echo "There are ".$errors." errors in the form. Chech if all requered fields are filled in!"; //error! Not all fields are set correctly
else //do some action
```

Comment: Both of your answers are nothing to do with CakePHP and therefore irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Sorry, didn't check the tags. CakePHP wasn't mentioned in the description of the problem and in the title. Can't help you, sorry.