# CakePHP validation array applying to many fields

Tags: php, cakephp

In a cake model I have 6 fields that all have the same validation rules. Is there a way to assign this rule to all 6 fields without having to copy-paste the array?

E.g.

```
public $currency_validate = array(
        'rule1'=>array(
            'rule'    => array('comparison', '>=', 0),
            'message' => 'Must be between 0 and 1'
            ),
        'rule2' => array(
            'rule'    => array('comparison', '<=', 1),
            'message' => 'Must be between 0 and 1'
            )
        );
public $validate = array(
            'usd' => $this->currency_validate,
            'gbp' => $this->currency_validate,
            'eur' => $this->currency_validate,
            //etc
        );
```

Does not work as one is not allowed to dynamical assign properties in a class.

Comment: Basic OOP. Use the constructor in this case then.

Comment: I tried that but if I put a `__construct` method in my model I get: Error: Call to a member function dispatchMethod() on a non-object

Comment: Try again. It is definitely possible.

Comment: You need to do it right - check the source code on how to properly overwrite model constructors.

Comment: possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574649/apply-same-validation-rule-for-multiple-fields

Comment: If I just put `function __construct(){}` in my model class I get the error.

Comment: maybe the code you posted above is only an example and your validation rule is more complex. But why don't you use `between` rule? I know this don't answer the main question thas is still valid, but maybe it helps...

Comment: I thought the between rule validates for string length rather than value

Comment: There's [`range`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#Validation::range)

Answer (score 0):

You can add rules into the **beforeValidate(array $options = array())** method:

```
public $currency_validate = array(
    'rule1'=>array(
        'rule'    => array('comparison', '>=', 0),
        'message' => 'Must be between 0 and 1'
        ),
    'rule2' => array(
        'rule'    => array('comparison', '<=', 1),
        'message' => 'Must be between 0 and 1'
        )
    );
public $validate = array(
        'usd' => array(),
        'gbp' => array(),
        'eur' => array(),
        //etc
    );

public function beforeValidate(array $options = array()) {
    $this->validate = array(
        'usd' => $this->currency_validate,
        'gbp' => $this->currency_validate,
        'eur' => $this->currency_validate,
        //etc
    );
    return true; //otherwise the current save() execution will abort 
}
```